# EF6 hangs when adding records to the db. (Oracle 11g - Where PK is handled by sequence/triggres)

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, oracle11g

I have an Oracle 11g table.

```
MY_TABLE
ID - decimal - PK
FIELD2 - varchar2
FIELD3 - varchar2
```

I create a sequence and trigger so that the ID field is incremented on an insert.

I verified that this works by inserting the some records via TOAD for Oracle.

I then went back to my c# application and created a List and using EF6 utilized the .AddRange(mylist).

On the context.SaveChanges() I got the an error for PK violation since I am not specifying the ID in the code.

I then read that I need to set the "StoreGeneratedPattern" property to "Identity" on the ID field in my EF model.

When I did that the error went away however when SaveChanges() executes it appears to be hanging and never adding any records.

How can I resolve this?

My code is rather simple:

```
public static void AddData(List<MY_TABLE> records)
{
    using (var context = new MyEntities())
    {
        context.MY_TABLE.AddRange(records);                
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

EDIT:
To clarify I re-tested adding 5 records and it appears to work.

However if I try to add 3K records then it appears to go on and on and on.

Comment: Are you adding a dummie value in each record or do you leave the field empty?

Comment: I am not adding a value so it should be empty.

Comment: Ok, I would add a value before adding it. EF could get confused when the PK value is empty..

Comment: My original attempt was to rad the DB and get the max value + 1 and then save the records.  It took about 4 minutes to load 3K of records.

Comment: Try and add the same value to all rows, like 1,  before adding them. In that way all rows have a PK and EF will send them to Oracle which will add the unique PK by the trigger.

Comment: No difference in my results.

Comment: EF inserts rows one-by-one which is very slow as each insert involves network roundtrip to database. If you want to DML many rows using full ORM like EF is extremely inefficient.

Comment: Is there a way to pass this data off to an Oracle Stored proc?  I wouldn't want to call the SP 3K times.